# Limit of $z_n = n(1-\cos(\theta/n) - i \sin(\theta/n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I wish to find the limit of the sequence $z_n = n(1-\cos(\theta/n) - i \sin(\theta/n))$, for some fixed $\theta$. To do so, I have separated the real and imaginary parts, observing

1. *Real Part:* $\text{Re}(z_n) = n - n cos(\theta/n).$ As $n$ becomes large, $\theta/n \rightarrow 0$, whence $$  (n - ncos(\theta/n)) \sim (n - n(1-\theta^2/2n^2)) = n  -n + \theta^2/2n  = \theta^2/2n \rightarrow 0, $$
   using a Taylor approximation.
2. *Imaginary Part:* $\text{Im}(z_n) = -n\sin(\theta/n).$ Using the same reasoning,
   $$-n\sin(\theta/n) \sim -n(\theta/n) \rightarrow -\theta.$$
   Accordingly, I've concluded that $z_n \rightarrow -i\theta.$ Would this line of reasoning be correct?

Comment: $\frac{1-\cos(\theta/n)}{1/n}+i\frac{\sin(\theta/n)-\sin(0)}{1/n}$. Use the definition of derivative of a function when passing to the limit.

Comment: yes, your reasoning is correct.